# C#: button image gets clipped on the bottom

Tags: c#, image, button, clipping, image-clipping

As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCAik.png), the image set on the button, gets bottom clipped for no apparent reason. The image is 24x24px big and the `AutoSize` property of the button is set to `True`.

The button is positioned directly on the window, so there can't be any layout messing with its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implicit margin inside of the `<button>` control. If you expand the button's height the clipping will disappear.

Comment: Expanding the button height by exactly 2px, indeed removes the clipping, but isn't there a solution to this other than always manually increasing the button height?

Comment: @カラス not that I'm aware of, unless you use an image that looks identical to the button :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as button's "BackgroundImage" property and then set the button's "BackgroundImageLayout" property as "Stretch".